# "TypeError: __ng_jsonp__.__req0 is null" on second jsonp call

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, callback, jsonp

I am writing a function to call the API of Forismatic to generate a random quote:

```
getQuote() {

    var quote: any = { quote:"", person: "", link: "" };

    var url = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/";
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );

    let params = {
      method: "getQuote",
      format: "jsonp",
      lang: "en",
      jsonp: "__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished" 
    }

    let options = new RequestOptions({ 
      headers: headers,
      method: 'Get',
      params: params
    });

    this.jsonp.get(url, options)
      .map( res => res.json() ) 
      .subscribe(q => {
        console.log(q)
        quote.quote = q.quoteText
        quote.person = q.quoteAuthor;
        quote.link = q.quoteLink;
       }, 
       error => {
        console.log(error);// Error getting the data
      }
    );
    return quote;
  }
```

The function works when the app is loaded. The console.log(q) prints an object like the following, which is the expected result:

```
Object { quoteText: "Criticism is something you can easily avoid by saying nothing, doing nothing, and being nothing.", quoteAuthor: "Aristotle", senderName: "", senderLink: "", quoteLink: "http://forismatic.com/en/9399c6b9a3/" }
```

However, if I call the function a second time (e.g. by copying a second line of the function call or by invoking it using a button), I get the following error:

```
Object { _body: "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "Ok", headers: {…}, type: 3, url: "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished" }

random-quote.ts:49:8
TypeError: __ng_jsonp__.__req0 is null[Learn More]
```

Any idea why this is happening? How can I fix it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function needs to be named differently on every JSONP request, ie. each callback is only usable once. Otherwise there would be no way to know which http.json call resulted in the callback function being called.

Angular has probably named the next callback as `__ng_jsonp__.__req1`, so you should just let Angular handle the callback naming.

If your server is looking for the callback name in a parameter named `jsonp` then you should be able to fix this simply by changing the jsonp value in params  to `jsonp: 'JSONP_CALLBACK'`. Angular will replace `JSONP_CALLBACK` with the correct callback name. By default, it also sets a parameter named `callback` with that value.

Comment: I replaced the "__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished" thing with "JSONP_CALLBACK" in the above code and now it's working. Thank you so much!